# Suggestion: have a Stackoverflow affiliate program

Tags: feature-request, affiliate

Now that you can associate accounts between SO, SF and SU and there being sister sites in How-To Geek and Doctype, why not have some kind of affiliate program so qualifying sites can associate with their SO/SU/SF user.

Perhaps there could be levels of affiliation too. Like migrating CSS/HTML questions from SO to Doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Neat suggestion, but with multiple disparate systems in play it may not be feasible. Of course, since I've never seen the StackExchange code, much less the code running DT or HtG, I'm probably not the most qualified to answer that. :)

I do think it'd be cool, though. (And that reminds me, I probably should jump into DT ... Except most of my HTML/CSS questions won't be publicly visible ... *sigh* ... )