# Close as belongs on doctype?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, doctype

If the pure HTML/CSS stuff is moving off of Stackoverflow on to Doctype, could we please get the close option for it?

Comment: I've left comments suggesting they may get a better answer there, but as it's not built on the same framework, and merely an associate, I imagine it would be difficult to migrate those closed answers. Maybe this is something Jeff 7 co. are working on, but I'd say that is a limiting factor -- if it were in place, then this would make a lot more sense

Comment: Been too long since a Doctype related question has appeared on Meta.

Comment: Jeff et. al. really need to clarify how the relationship between SO and Doctype is supposed to work. Given, I haven't listened to the lastest few podcasts yet.

Comment: Apparently it's not just the normal questions of SO moving out, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13929/doctype-leaving/14043#14043 - where was the settling in period?

Comment: It seems the consensus is that this shouldn't be implemented, because we should keep HTML/CSS questions on SO. How is picking an accepted answer supposed to work on meta?

Answer (score 22):

I am fairly active in HTML/CSS on SO and I'd hate for questions to start being nudged to this 3rd party site. I think we can certainly let them know there's a designer-centric website that can help, but if someone wants an answer to their question on the far more popular and mature engine of SO or perhaps just from a programming perspective I don't see why we should discourage that.

Comment: I think its quite valuable to have all the X questions in one place. So, if we're going to keep them on SO, then we shouldn't send people to Doctype at all. It'd be painful to have to search multiple SO-affiliated sites whenever you have a CSS question (or when you want to answer one), and confusing as to which site to put it on.

Comment: Put me down as another person who'd hate to see the HTML/CSS stuff leave SO whole hog.

Comment: I too would not like to see this.  I have signed up on DocType and I think it looks very slick, but I like StackOverflow for the reason it was created. Its a place to come for *ALl* your programming questions.  DocType works well for all the "corner case" HTML/CSS issues where you need and want someone to run your code and debug what isn't working, but when you have more general questions [why does parseInt() in JavaScript sometimes fail ;-) ] then those questions belong here.  DocType will gain a niche community on its own it doesn't need SO's help.

Comment: @derobert: I agree it should all be on one site, but I think that site should be SO.

Answer (score 8):

While DocType has some really cool features, it is not quite up to SO for usability. It would help tremendously if they decreased the font-size and gave me back some of my screen real estate so I can see more than two questions at a time.

Until the usability improves I don't think there is going to be any great migration to DocType.

And frankly, I am kinda bummed that I have to start over as far as rep goes.

Comment: Look at it from a designer's perspective. Either the screen is too small to contain their awesome work or the user should be just fine squinting at 3x3 pixel font.

Comment: Huge font is a pet peeve of mine. It has its place in some designs but if information is your commodity I'd think you'd want as much of it on the screen as possible.

Comment: There really is just something about the font size on Doctype that makes it feel clunky. It's way too large and at the current size, the normal posts all look like they're in bold.

Answer (score 5):

For most web developers I think the distinction between programming and designing for the web is artificial.  Most of the people I know do both.  We do have a few web designers for static sites, but I only make use of them in very rare circumstances -- say to get a logo or come up with a color scheme.  The rest of the HTML/CSS is mine, and I like it that way.  And, when you're enhancing your interface via javascript, there's really no getting away from it.

It would actually be a step backwards for me to have to go to two different sites depending on what type of development problem I may be having.  While most of the affiliations make sense to me, the affiliation with DocType really doesn't.  There's a real overlap with the subject matter and it doesn't provide the sort of drilldown depth of HowToGeek. Affiliating with A List Apart, or something similar, would have made more sense to me.

I would rather see SO be more explicit about allowing those sorts of HTML/CSS questions than offer a close as belongs on DocType so people aren't tempted to close them as not programming related.

Just to be clear, my issues aren't with DocType.  I'm sure it's a fine forum, but the whole point of SO was to bring development related problems and solutions into a single forum.  Adding DocType to the League of Justice seems to detract from that goal, not add to it.

Answer (score 4):

We don't have a way to migrate to Doctype. Until we do I think voting to closed as belonging there doesn't really work. I've suggested having an [affiliate program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14167/suggestion-have-a-stackoverflow-affiliate-program), which might include such things as migrating to/from third-party sites. I don't know if SO has any plans for this or anything related.

Also, what about the existing HTML/CSS questions? A lot of old questions from SO have subsequently been migrated to SU, SF and here. We can't do that either. All in all I don't think we can exclude HTML/CSS questions. We can just encourage them going to Doctype.